# reverse geocoding in bash

Tags: bash, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, scripting

I have a gps unit which extracts longitude and latitude and outputs as a google maps link

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=51.601154,-0.404765&sensor=false
```

From this i'd like to call it via curl and display the "short name" in line 20

```
"short_name" : "Northwood",
```

so i'd just like to be left with

```
Northwood
```

so something like

```
curl -s http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=latlng=51.601154,-0.404765&sensor=false sed sort_name
```

Comment: Is there a question?  have you tried it? Are you having issues?  If so, what are they?

Answer (score 3):

Mmmm, this is kind of quick and dirty:

```
curl -s "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false" | grep -B 1 "route" | awk -F'"' '/short_name/ {print $4}'
Bedford Avenue
```

It looks for the line before the line with "route" in it, then the word "short_name" and then prints the 4th field as detected by using " as the field separator. Really you should use a JSON parser though!

Notes:

1. This doesn't require you to install anything.
2. I look for the word "route" in the JSON because you seem to want the road name - you could equally look for anything else you choose.
3. This isn't a very robust solution as Google may not always give you a route, but I guess other programs/solutions won't work then either!
4. You can play with my solution by successively removing parts from the right hand end of the pipeline to see what each phase produces.

**EDITED**

Mmm, you have changed from JSON to XML, I see... well, this parses out what you want, but I note you are now looking for a locality whereas before you were looking for a route or road name? Which do you want?

```
curl -s "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=51.601154,-0.404765&sensor=false" | grep -B1 locality | grep short_name| head -1|sed -e 's/<\/.*//' -e 's/.*>//'
```

The "grep -B1" looks for the line before the line containing "locality". The "grep short_name" then gets the locality's short name. The "head -1" discards all but the first locality if there are more than one. The "sed" stuff removes the <> XML delimiters.

Comment: thanks for that it seems the output for the US and UK differ I have update my original post, could you tell me how to tweak yours.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't text, it's structured JSON. You don't want the value after the colon on line 12, you want the value of short name in the address_component with type 'route' from the result.

You could do this with `jsawk` or `python`, but it's easier to get it from XML output with `xmlstarlet`, which is lighter than python and more available than jsawk. Install `xmlstarlet` and try:

```
curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false' \
| xmlstarlet sel -t -v '/GeocodeResponse/result/address_component[type="route"]/short_name'
```

This is much more robust than trying to parse JSON as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work assuming you always like the `short_name` at line 12:

```
curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=false' | sed -n -e '12s/^.*: "\([a-zA-Z ]*\)",/\1/p'
```

or if you are using the `xml` api and wan't to trap the `short_name` on line 20:

```
curl -s 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=51.601154,-0.404765&sensor=false' | sed -n -e '19s/<short_name>\([a-zA-Z ]*\)<\/short_name>/\1/p'
```